# Rails form inline

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a nav bar in a rails project like this

```
<nav>
    <%= link_to "Home", root_url %> |
    <%= form_tag "/posts", :method => 'get' do %>
        <%= search_field_tag 'search', nil, :placeholder => 'Find...' %>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_url %> |
    <%= link_to "Sign In", sign_in_url %>
</nav>
```

And I want it to show up all in one line. It currently renders with the search bar on its own line with the other links above an below it.  When I inspect the form element it seems to be taking up the entire page width.  I've tried wrapping the form tag in  a div with `display: inline` and manually setting its width but neither works.  How can I force them to show up on the same line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `ul li` in your `view` and add a little `css` like the following

### View:

```
   <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <%= link_to "Home", root_url %>
        </li>
        <li>
          <%= form_tag "/posts", :method => 'get' do %>
            <%= search_field_tag 'search', nil, :placeholder => 'Find...' %>
          <% end %>
        </li>
        <li>
          <%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_url %>
        </li>
        <li>
          <%= link_to "Sign In", sign_in_url %>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

In this case, you do not want to add a `|` to end of the tag. `CSS` will do that thing. It's the HTML 5 semantic and proper way to get the divider in between the menu's.

### Css:

```
ul li {
    display: inline;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

li:last-child { border-right:none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<nav>
  <div style= "display:inline">
    <%= link_to "Home", root_url %> |
  </div>

  <div style= "display:inline">
    <%= form_tag "/posts", :method => 'get' do %>
      <%= search_field_tag 'search', nil, :placeholder => 'Find...' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

     <%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_url %> |
     <%= link_to "Sign In", sign_in_url %>
</nav>
```